# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, mysql-error-1055

Receiving the following error:

```
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'world.country.Code' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

When running the following query:

```
select countrylanguage.language, country.code, sum(country.population*countrylanguage.percentage/100)
from countrylanguage
join country on countrylanguage.countrycode = country.code
group by countrylanguage.language
order by sum(country.population*countrylanguage.percentage) desc ;
```

Using the MySQL world test database (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html). No idea why this is happening. Currently running MYSQL 5.7.10.

Any ideas??? :O

Comment: You have the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option enabled, which removes MySQL's relaxed rules about `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The default for that option changed in MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @Barmar Changed from what to what?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt From off to on.

Answer (score 31):

As @Brian Riley already said you should either remove 1 column in your select

```
select countrylanguage.language ,sum(country.population*countrylanguage.percentage/100)
from countrylanguage
join country on countrylanguage.countrycode = country.code
group by countrylanguage.language
order by sum(country.population*countrylanguage.percentage) desc ;
```

or add it to your grouping

```
select countrylanguage.language, country.code, sum(country.population*countrylanguage.percentage/100)
from countrylanguage
join country on countrylanguage.countrycode = country.code
group by countrylanguage.language, country.code
order by sum(country.population*countrylanguage.percentage) desc ;
```

Comment: or just run from the mysql command line: SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: This runs but produces no effect

Comment: I had to additionally set it on the session: `SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

Answer (score -3):

`country.code` is not in your `group by` statement, and is not an aggregate (wrapped in an aggregate function).

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_sqlserver.asp

Comment: The link is not working anymore, try to post actual content in place of hyperlinks while answering.

Comment: This is not a question about SQL Server anyway.